# "str2Int(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what my compiler isn't liking. I promise that I'm using StackOverflow as a last resort and that I'm trying my best to troubleshoot by myself.

**"str2Int(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
_main in main.o**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool valid_equation(const std::string&); 
int str2Int(const std::string&);

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    std::cout << str2Int("0034");

    //std::cout << valid_equation("5*2+3"); 

    return 0;
}

/*
bool valid_equation(const std::string& eq) { 
    std::string::const_iterator it = eq.begin(); 



} 
*/

int str2int(const std::string& str) {

    // Still need to add error checking 

    int i = 0;
    std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin();
    while (it != str.end()) {
        i *= 10;
        i += *it++ - '0';
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: If you are using c++11 then I would highly recommend just using the library function to do this `std::stoi( str )` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 5):

Use consistent capitalization. `str2Int` is not the same as `str2int`.

Comment: Whoops ... Sorry. Not sure how I didn't see that.

Comment: @user2967799, no need to apologize, we all make mistakes like this once in a while. If this solved your problem please accept this answer.

Comment: People ask me how I spot errors so quickly.  I answer that I got quite a lot of practice making my own.  :-)  BTW, @shuttle87, there's a 15 min delay after the question's asked before it can be selected as an answer.